# Google OAuth2 authenticate and API on PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, token

I have created a button that allows users to sign in with Google.

After the users choose their google accounts, I can get the following parameters as response from Google.

access tokens
id_token
expires_in
token_type
created

How can I use these parameters to use services provide from Google?

For example, can I create buttons for user to go to the gmail boxes?

If it is not the way, what are the uses of those token?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's tokens id you can get User's Information like Name Email.

You cant provide direct option to open Gmail. It will prompt user to login

You can refer this doc for more info  [Gmail scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)

Comment: So even I got the access tokens stuffs,
I can't to let them use Google Services like Google drive or Gmail?
Because actually I am doing something like Single Sign On, I want to bring convenience to the users so they could login by Google and may provide buttons linked to Google service without logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing Google services, you need the `access_token`. When you are creating the authentication URL, you must specify all scopes - permissions (from [this list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)) you want to use in your application. Then Google will ask the user for consent with delegating those permissions to your application. The access token you get will allow you to perform those actions.

You can go through those Google API scopes and get an idea what you can do and what not. For example you cannot use the GMail GUI, but you can read, send, delete, and manage user's emails, send new emails and so.

Comment: Now, I added the drive in the scope.
Then, how can I use the access_token to perform actions on the Google Drive?

Comment: Check the Google Drive API doc. There are even ready to use PHP code samples https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Comment: Yeah, I have tried step by step according to the tutorial.
But there are error and I cannot figure out the solution.
After I type php quickstart.php in terminal, then there are error messages as below

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'missing the required redirect URI' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sso-test/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php:639
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sso-test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(340): Google\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sso-test/quickstart.php(36): Google_Client->createAuthUrl()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sso-test/quickstart.php(75): getClient()
#3 {main}
`

Comment: `thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sso-test/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php on line 639`

Comment: As it's saying, you probably didn't specify the redirect URI as a request parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that error message. But the tutorial did not specify what redirect uri it should be.

Comment: It must be one of the registered URIs for your client_id. You were supposed to enter some redirect URIs when you were registering your application at Google API console https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: but the example did not set any redirect uri, I know I have to register redirect URIs in Google API console.